# Build views in Plone only with Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, plone, zope

Is there any way to write a view in Plone using only Python? I found a way for forms, but what else can you build for views ? Without tal expressions

Link: https://docs.plone.org/4/en/develop/addons/helloworld/extend/form.html